# get posts of category in JPA, mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

i have two tables: category table and post table. they have one-to-many relationship, a record in category table can have many matching records in post table.
I'm using JPA, hibernate, MySQL. If I want to get all posts of category, i have two ways. first way: find a category then get all posts of that category. second way: `SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE p.category = :category`. As you know, category field in post table is a foreign key and is indexed. So the query in second way will executed fast. I want to ask which way i should use? Why?
Thanks

Comment: Frankly, it doesn't matter much. The second one will be marginally faster, except if the collection of posts is already loaded in the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the one that makes more sense in code. Make your code clear and easy to refactor until you have performance issues.

I would use the way that doesn't require you to write any queries. This makes it easier for you to change things up later when you do have performance issues. You can probably make better use of your time optimizing the slow parts of your program.

For performance, a single trip to the database is faster than multiple trips. Hence, one query would be faster. If there are many fields, you will also want to consider limiting the number of fields you are fetching to improve performance.